# Windows Server 2008 R2 C Drive losing space by the hour

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a server that has been behaving as normal for years now. In the last few days, something has happened. (I can't document exactly when, as I only know theres an issue with this box when someone tells me..)

The Box serves websites.
All Sites, IIS, Logs Database and DB logs / files are on a D Partition.

Now I can see that I am losing approx 1/2 a GB per hour on the C Drive.

I am not a sys admin, and we don't have one available here, so I am struggling to pin down where this is going wrong, and how / why.

So, are there any built in tools I can use to identify what is happening here, or at least help me see which folder is growing, so I can start to track down what is going on?

Comment: Download a program such as windirstat, treesize and run it (As Administrator) this will give you a graphical layout of the drive, This should help you identify where the space is being used

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about built in tools but they will all require some upfront configuration, however [Treesize Free](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) will show you whats in use where quickly and easily.

Remember to run it as administrator.

Comment: That shows that Windows is using 28.2GB at present.
17.5GB of that is in winsxs.
I ran DiskCleanup, and that claimed it would recover 5 - 6 GB of space. In the end it recovered about 400mb. So to the uneducated it would seem that the winsxs folder is the issue.

Comment: WinSXS is a bit of a nightmare, it effectively holds a load of different versions of similar DLL/runtime files. When you install a new program or Windows updates you may see expansion in the WinSXS folder, but you wouldn't expect to see continuous expansion of that folder without explicitly making changes. You say you see continuous expansion. If you save the treesize out put and then run it again which folders have changed in size?

Comment: Disk Cleanup needs to run as administrator too, or it won't be able to access loads of hte locations it looks at for clean up.

Comment: I'll run Disk Cleanup as Admin, to buy me some time, then base line TreeSize, and see whats happened an hour later. Thanks
Update: Disk Cleanup as Admin hasn't touched the WinSXS folder.

Comment: Windows Update has been failing since the 14th. It triggers at 03.00 am here. So Is it feasible that the updates are failing because they need more space than is available to install. But then the system can't tidy them up as they haven't succeeded? 9If so, I'm caught in a catch 22 situation

Comment: Its a possibility. how much space do you have free, what % is that of total?

Comment: 1.19 GB free of a 32.4 GB drive. so about 3.5%. Something else that has struck me is that theres lots of web apps on the D drive. (Unaffected.) But is it possible the 8 GB of ram is insufficient, and the reducing space on the C drive is because disk space is being used as temporary memory in a swap file (Apologies if that went out with the arc :D)

Comment: Your swap file is probably of fixed size (equal to or 1.5x the physical ram). Did you compare the first treesize with a new one. Once we know the folder we know whats happening.

Comment: Its the Windows and Users Folders that are increasing. I didn't have the users folder expanded. The Windows Folder, it was Microsoft.NET and System32 folders. Its hard to be too precise, as my maths was off a bit earlier (to0 many zeros). We have lost 600 mb in the last 3.5 hours. (Queue you telling me thats normal during daily operation!)

Comment: Don't mess with the WinSxS folder, unless you are using tools designed to do so, like Disk Cleanup.  Many (but not all) files in the WinSxS folder are hard links which basically means there are multiple directory entries for the same file, but the file only takes up the space once.  Deleting hard linked files does not free up disk space unless it is the last link to a file.  Disk Cleanup is smart enough to know which WinSxS files are the last remaining link _and_ are not needed and it leaves the rest alone.

Comment: @Matt No one else brought that up, so I'll ask - can you expand drive C (it might require some server down-time)? 30GB is not nearly enough if you update Windows regularly (or automatically), you need to at least double it.

Comment: I can try to do that this evening. Though as I am not trained in this, it could be interesting! Assume it is done via Computer Manager -> Disk Management ? How risky is this, do I need to wait until all the backups have run on the D Drive?

Comment: I do this all the time in VMWare and not lost a machine once. At the same time you run the risk of corrupting the OS disk and losing the server entirely. If you are running on hardware you might struggle as the free space you can free up to expand into will be stuck at 'the other end' of the D drive so your OS disk can't expand into it. If you don't know what you are doing and this is runinng anything even slightly important be very very careful (don't do it!).

Comment: Any further details on the user folders that are expanding? Again, wouldn't expect them to just get bigger without any specific actions to cause it. Additionally I won't expect an OS disk to loose 600MB in 3 hours unless I was doing something to cause that.

Comment: I'll look some more tomorrow. I've kept it running all today so that they can run reports, get their backups done and so on. This box is running fairly critical stuff, so I am guessing that this falls into the 'dont resize the disks' category for now.

Comment: Fustrratingly, the issue has gone away. I managed to make enough space last night for teh windows updates to run. They ran, tidied up after themselves leaving me with 9gb of space, and nothing is eating it up today. Guess I'll have to put it down to an unknown Ms Update issue. Thanks for all the suggestions, and also for pointing me towards Treezize free